# X,Y,Z independent and $\sim N(1,1)$. Find $P(X+Y \geqq 3Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm stuck on this problem, and I dont know how to continue from here. It would be great if someone could just give me a hint of how to proceed from here.

The problem is,

> "Let $X,Y,Z$ be independent and $N(1,1)$. Find $P(X+Y \geqq 3Z)$."

Now, the way I see it there are two obvious ways to proceed. First off, one can simply condition on the different variables and because of their independence obtain

$P(X+Y \geqq 3Z) = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X+Y \geqq 3Z | Z=z)f_Z(z)dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}P(X+Y \geqq 3z)f_Z(z)dz $   $ (1)$

and by doing the exact same reasoning we get $P(X+Y \geqq 3z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_X(3z-y)f_Y(y)dy$

and thus (with (1))

$P(X+Y \geqq 3Z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f_Z(z)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F_X(3z-y)f_Y(y)dydz$.

This is problematic however, since $X\sim N(1,1)$ means that we cannot express $F_X(3z-y)$ explicitly. If the variables would have had some other distribution with known cdf, the calculation could continue in a straight forward way from here. This is not the case right now, however. I did, however, try to use the fact that $F_X(3z-y) = \int_{0}^{3z-y}f_X(t)dt$. But then I couldnt make sense of the integration limits. So I doubt that this is the right way to go in solving this particular problem.

I was also thinking about using the fact that $X+Y =: W$ then $W\sim N(1+1,1+1)$ and would simplify the calculation above but yield the same problem. Maybe there is a nice trick one can use in calculating the integral above. Either way, I would really appreciate if someone could give me some hints as to how to continue from here.

Thanks!

Comment: You can directly find the probability that $X+Y-3Z$ is positive from its distribution; the answer would be in terms of the standard normal cdf.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure if I follow. As i noted above, the distribution of the sum of two normal distributions are also normal with the sum of variances and means. In this case, e.g. $X+Y \sim N(2,2)$. So if I let $W=X+Y-3Z$ and given that $X,Y,Z \sim N(1,1)$, what can I say about $W$? Obviously it cannot be that $W \sim N(2 -3, 2 -3) = N(-1,-1)$

Comment: No, the normal reproductive property gives you $X+Y-3Z\sim N(1+1-3,1+1+9)$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks. However, is there not anyway to solve the problem using the method above?

Comment: There has to be. That is not the only way to do it.

Comment: Yes ok. The corresponding chapter in my text book talks about convolution and describes methods like the one I proposed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT 1:** Recall (or prove) that if $X \sim N(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$ are independent, then $X + Y \sim N(\mu_1 + \mu_2, \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2)$.

**HINT 2:** Recall (or prove) that if $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $a$ is constant, then $aX\sim N(a\mu, a^2\sigma^2)$.

**HINT 3:** Rearrange the equation $X + Y \geq 3Z$ so there's just one random variable on one side of the equation and $0$ on the other.

Answer (score 1):

An other way :

$$P(X+Y\geq 3Z)=\iiint_{\{x+y\geq 3z\}}f_{(X,Y,Z)}(x,y,z)dxdydz$$
where $$f_{(X,Y,Z)}=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{3/2}}e^{(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2+(z-1)^2}.$$