# Let $X, Y, Z$ be independent and $N(1,1).$ Find the probability that $X + Y ≥ 3Z$ using convolution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I did the following: Let $W=X+Y-3Z,$ then we have that

$$W\sim N(1+1-3,1+1+9)=N(-1,11).$$

so

$$P(X+Y\ge3Z)=P(W\ge 0)=1-P(W\le 0)=1-F_W(0)=1-\Phi\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{11}}\right)\approx \\ \approx 1-0.618 = 0.382.$$

However, I'm in the chapter treating *convolution*. How can I solve this problem using this approach instead?

Comment: If you have been made familiar already with the nice properties of normal distribution then I think that the way you treated this question is excellent. Maybe the question was asked in the chapter *convolution* just to somehow 'seduce' people to apply that cumbersome and unnecessary tool. You are 'succeeded' if you leave it aside.

Comment: The [same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2765119/x-y-z-independent-and-sim-n1-1-find-pxy-geqq-3z) here has been solved like you did. The OP asked for convolution as well. But she accepted  the answer without convolution.

Comment: @callculus - Yes I searched for this answer here before I posted it and saw that post you are reffering to aswell. However it did not show how to solve this using convolution, thus I asked this question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You may not want to do it** by **convolution** as you would see after I lay out the solution.

Let us define a random variable $W = X+Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are $N(1,1)$.

$$f_W(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_Y(y)f_X(w-y)dy$$

$$f_W(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-1)^2}{2}}.\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(w-y-1)^2}{2}}dy$$

$$f_W(w) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{(w^2-2w+2)}{2}}.e^{-\frac{(2y^2-2wy)}{2}}dy$$

From Wolfram Alpha.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(2y^2-2wy)}{2}}dy = \sqrt{\pi}{e^{\frac{w^2}{4}}}$$

$$f_W(w) =\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(w^2-2w+2)}{2}}.e^{\frac{w^2}{4}}$$

$$f_W(w) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(w-2)^2}{2{\sqrt{2}}^2}}$$

which is what $N(2,2)$

Now Let us define $M = W-3Z = W+U$ where $W \text{ is } N(2,2)$ and $(-3Z = U) \text{ is }  N(-3,9)$

$$f_M(m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_W(w)f_U(m-w)dw$$

$$f_M(m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-\frac{(w-2)^2}{4}}.\frac{1}{3\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(m-w+3)^2}{2.(9)}}dw$$

$$f_M(m) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{6\sqrt{2}\pi}e^{-\frac{(2m^2+12m+54)}{36}}.e^{-\frac{(11w^2-4wm-48w)}{36}}dw$$

From Wolfram Alpha.
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-\frac{(11w^2-4wm-48w)}{2}}dw = \frac{6\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{11}}e^{\frac{(m+12)^2}{99}}$$

$$f_M(m) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{22\pi}}e^{-\frac{(2m^2+12m+54)}{36}}.{e^{\frac{(m+12)^2}{99}}}$$

$$f_M(m) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{22\pi}}e^{-\frac{(m+1)^2}{22}}$$

which is what $N(-1,11)$.

Now tell me if you would want to do it by convolution.  You can't integrate some nasty integrals.

Comment: Thank you! I now see why the other method is preferable.